# Archetype for Maven Project

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-archetype

I'd like to start a little project with maven. I want to use JSF2 and Hibernate. Can you recommend some archetype? or some other procedures to start this project.

Cheers...

Comment: My recommendation would be to stay away from Maven ;) But when I do use Maven, I do it in Eclipse, and the wizard offers me a selection of archetypes automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

A list with some archetypes will appear. You may find them useful/educative since many of them are for JSF projects:

```
1: internal -> appfuse-basic-jsf (AppFuse archetype for creating a web application with Hibernate, Spring and JSF)
...
6: internal -> appfuse-modular-jsf (AppFuse archetype for creating a modular application with Hibernate, Spring and JSF)
...
20: internal -> softeu-archetype-seam (JSF+Facelets+Seam Archetype)
21: internal -> softeu-archetype-seam-simple (JSF+Facelets+Seam (no persistence) Archetype)
22: internal -> softeu-archetype-jsf (JSF+Facelets Archetype)
23: internal -> jpa-maven-archetype (JPA application)
...
39: internal -> myfaces-archetype-jsfcomponents (A simple archetype for create custom JSF components using MyFaces)
```

(I do not agree with Carl, keep it up with maven!)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.github.happyfaces -DarchetypeArtifactId=happyfaces-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2 -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=MyTestApp
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems like to want produce a war, isn't it ?
As a consequence, may i suggest you to use the `war` packaging, which will allow you to run your web project in dev mode (also notice that, with [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) and [eclipse WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/), you may have added bonuses).